# Performance-tuning a simple 2D Table construct

Tags: performance-tuning

I've recently been playing with some performance tuning over a seemingly simple construction where I build a 2D array of `Sin[x*y]` for `{x, y}∈Interval[{0, 2π}, {0, 2π}]`.

I think it's also a good example of how vastly different results one can get depending on how efficiently the operation is performed.

Here's the operation in the simplest/least efficient way I could think up:

```
Table[N@Sin[x*y], 
    {x, 0, 2π, π/250},  
    {y, 0, 2π, π/250}
    ]; // RepeatedTiming // First

2.01
```

Now, how can we speed this up? (or slow it down in non-intuitive ways)

For reference, the best I managed to get was `0.0011` but all answers are good answers, especially if they provide analysis of how they speed up/slow down the problem.

Also feel free to cut down on the number of points `250` was simply most evocative.

Comment: BTW, in our culture, 250 can mean the word "fool(ish)". Is it a coincidence?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ 1000%. I didn't know that.

Comment: Then what a coincidence! (For "least efficient")

Answer (score 7):

Use packed arrays, and vector operations. Here are 2 possibilities:

```
Table[N@Sin[x*y],{x,0,2π,π/12},{y,0,2π,π/12}]; //RepeatedTiming//First

With[{pa=Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ Range[0,2π,π/12]},
    Sin @ Outer[Times, pa, pa]
]; //RepeatedTiming//First

With[{pa=Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ Range[0,2π,π/12]},
    Sin @ KroneckerProduct[pa, pa]
]; //RepeatedTiming//First
```

> 0.0025
>
> 0.0000322
>
> 0.0000314

**Update**

It seems that converting to a packed array takes the most time, so here is a version that avoids packing:

```
With[{pa = Range[0, 24] N[Pi/12]},
    Sin @ KroneckerProduct[pa, pa]
]; //RepeatedTiming //First
```

> 8.3*10^-6

Comment: I like the use of `KroneckerProduct`. I hadn't thought to use that.

Comment: `Range[0., 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/ 500]` or `Subdivide[0., 2 Pi, 500]` are even faster because they generate packed arrays right from the start.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher oh good thinking with `Subdivide`. My brain just immediately jumps to `Range` but there's really no reason for that. It also looks like `Subdivide` blows `Range` out of the water here...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher another odd subtle point... `Range[0., 2. \[Pi], \[Pi]/250]` is much slower than `Range[0., 2. \[Pi], \[Pi]/250.]`

Answer (score 6):

```
With[{r = Range[0., 2Pi, Pi/12.] }, Sin @ Outer[Times, r, r]];// RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.000014